sql magic in jupyter notebooks
I'm new to jupyter notebooks, but wanna learn it. Currently I'm trying out some basic db opperations with sql magic. I can build a connection and create a new table. But when I try to read out the table this non specific error occurs. Can anybody help me out?
My "code":

Loading stuff:

import sys
print(sys.executable)
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine
import pandas as pd
%load_ext sql

#setup database connection
%sql postgresql://postgres:postgres@localhost:5432/rain


Create Table:

%%sql
CREATE TABLE people (first text, last text, drink text);
INSERT INTO people (first,last,drink)
VALUES
    ('zaphod','beeblebrox','pan galactic gargle blaster'),
    ('arthur','dent','tea'),
    ('ford','prefect','old janx spirit')
    ;


trying to get the table:

%sql select * from people;

The Error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[40], line 1
----> 1 get_ipython().run_cell_magic('sql', '', '\nselect * from people;\n')

File ~/.local/share/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.12/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py:2541, in InteractiveShell.run_cell_magic(self, magic_name, line, cell)
   2539 with self.builtin_trap:
   2540     args = (magic_arg_s, cell)
-> 2541     result = fn(*args, **kwargs)
   2543 # The code below prevents the output from being displayed
   2544 # when using magics with decorator @output_can_be_silenced
   2545 # when the last Python token in the expression is a ';'.
   2546 if getattr(fn, magic.MAGIC_OUTPUT_CAN_BE_SILENCED, False):

File ~/.local/share/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sql/magic.py:219, in SqlMagic.execute(self, line, cell, local_ns)
    216     return
    218 try:
--> 219     result = sql.run.run(conn, parsed["sql"], self, user_ns)
    221     if (
    222         result is not None
    223         and not isinstance(result, str)
   (...)
    226         # Instead of returning values, set variables directly in the
    227         # user's namespace. Variable names given by column names
    229         if self.autopandas:

File ~/.local/share/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sql/run.py:374, in run(conn, sql, config, user_namespace)
    372     if result and config.feedback:
    373         print(interpret_rowcount(result.rowcount))
--> 374 resultset = ResultSet(result, config)
    375 if config.autopandas:
    376     return resultset.DataFrame()

File ~/.local/share/pipx/venvs/jupyterlab/lib/python3.12/site-packages/sql/run.py:116, in ResultSet.__init__(self, sqlaproxy, config)
    114         list.__init__(self, sqlaproxy.fetchall())
    115     self.field_names = unduplicate_field_names(self.keys)
--> 116     self.pretty = PrettyTable(self.field_names, style=prettytable.__dict__[config.style.upper()])
    117 else:
    118     list.__init__(self, [])

KeyError: 'DEFAULT'



You need to include version information in your question. Add to question text, as text the following: 1) Python version. 2) Jupyter version 3) prettytable version. Though at a guess this is due to this issue prettytable new version 3.12.0 is conflicting

From the log message error is thrown from prettyTable, could be related to how results are rendered.
Try setting this, this will return the results in a plain text format.
%config SqlMagic.style = 'PLAIN'

Also try setting this for prettyTable
%config SqlMagic.style = 'DEFAULT'


both times the same error message ... i just added your suggestion into the code ... dont know if I have to do something more specific when trying to sets something for prettyTable.

See the comment above, can you add all the versions that you are using?

(sorry for the late answer I was on vacation) I updated the post concerning your questions... hope it helps, if you need more just ask ;_)
